# Can I create a JEE Web App with Intellij Community Edition?

Tags: intellij-idea, jakarta-ee

I want to create a JEE Web App with Intellij Community edition, so I want to learn about Servlets and JSP and I have Intellij Community edition and I want to know if I could create a JEE Web App with it. Until now I've worked only with simple Java SE projects and when I click File/New/Project, I don't see an option for Java Enterprise:

[image]

Is there a possibility to create a JEE Web App with Intellij Community edition? And how? I know that you can create Spring Boot apps using Maven, so I think that I could be a possibility for JEE Web App too. Thank you!

Comment: If you're "wanting to learn", skip servlets and JSP; they're legacy technology. Use Spring MVC (or Spring WebFlux) instead and don't worry about manually interacting with the servlet system. (And use Thymeleaf if you're doing HTML templating; it has several advantages over JSP.)

Comment: Ok thanks, but all the job requirements ask about JEE.

Comment: Java EE is only available "out of the box" with the Ultimate Edition (**File > New > Project... > Java Enterprise > ...**), but it is still possible to create Java EE applications using the Community Edition with some extra effort. To get started try going through [the results of this search on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bintellij-idea%5D+community+%22java+ee%22) to see what is helpful to you.

Comment: If the create dialog for Java EE is missing in the community edition, you can fallback on creating the project using a Maven Archetype (e.g. https://rieckpil.de/howto-bootstrap-a-java-ee-8-and-microprofile-2-0-maven-project-in-seconds/) and then import the project as a normal Maven project